# How Can I add HTML And CSS Into PDF

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, pdf-generation

I have an HTML (not XHTML) document that renders fine in Firefox 3 and IE 7.  It uses fairly basic CSS to style it and renders fine in HTML.

I'm now after a way of converting it to PDF.  I have tried:

- [DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf): it had huge problems with tables.  I factored out my large nested tables and it helped (before it was just consuming up to 128M of memory then dying--thats my limit on memory in php.ini) but it makes a complete mess of tables and doesn't seem to get images.  The tables were just basic stuff with some border styles to add some lines at various points;
- [HTML2PDF and HTML2PS](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf): I actually had better luck with this.  It rendered some of the images (all the images are Google Chart URLs) and the table formatting was much better but it seemed to have some complexity problem I haven't figured out yet and kept dying with unknown node_type() errors.  Not sure where to go from here; and
- [Htmldoc](http://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1): this seems to work fine on basic HTML but has almost no support for CSS whatsoever so you have to do everything in HTML (I didn't realize it was still 2001 in Htmldoc-land...) so it's useless to me.

I tried a Windows app called Html2Pdf Pilot that actually did a pretty decent job but I need something that at a minimum runs on Linux and ideally runs on-demand via PHP on the Webserver.

What am I missing, or how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Html2Pdf actually uses an embedded instance of IE to render the page, then converts that to PDF - probably through IE's print mechanism.

Comment: since it's a 2008 question, dompdf is much more mature now. ;-)

Comment: dompdf now supports CSS 2.1 and can deal with `@import`, `@media` and `@screen` rules, and will load external stylesheets. It also comes bundled with everything required for it to work, although there are things you can install to get better performance than the default libs. http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

Comment: I gues that the right thing to do is to make browsers produce the pdf becuase they are the only ones doing proper rendering. see this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/25574082/39998

Comment: 2015 Update: After researching a lot of options we decided to go with wkhtmltopdf its a nice utility we struggle with CSS because we have external CSS file but then we applied the trick of putting a dummy link of CSS on our HTML element which we want to convert and setting the right path it works like MAGIC !!!

Comment: [Other suggestions in this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190635/how-to-convert-html-into-pdf-with-php)

Comment: There are two versions of HTML2PDF. The really old one (2009) linked to here and the newer French one which I talk about in my answer.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/10641667/287948

Comment: @HendraUzia Sadly, dompdf still has huge issues with table rendering. It adds blank pages in the document

Comment: Here is a tutorial on DOMPDF.
http://advancetechtutorial.blogspot.com/2015/09/pdf-generate-in-codeigniter-using-dompdf.html

Comment: you can convert your html w/ styles to a canvas using html2canvas, then convert the canvas to an image using canvasObj.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), append the image to the DOM and pass that to your PHP generator

Comment: How about using Google Chrome, there you get the option to **save as pdf** from "Print" option.

Comment: check this php5 library https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy easy to use and it uses "wkhtmltopdf"

Comment: I believe soon everyone finds Chrome/Chromium headless `chrome --headless --print-to-pdf="path/to/pdf" https://your_url
` as richest, fastest and easiest html to pdf generation tool http://crbug.com/603559 as it supports most of html features developers rely on web development and doesn't suck on complex scripts like most of the other libraries and tools do.

Comment: You'r right, Chrome headless should render well, but, would run on node, not php.

Comment: This question is off-topic at SO, but on-topic in softwarerecs.SE. See [How can I convert HTML with CSS to PDF?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/45903/1834).

Comment: This question brings back my 2010 memories with PHP and DOMPDF. :)

Comment: Dompdf is another option. https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Comment: @Hendra Uzia Not mature enough... DOM PDF is absolutely worst... just did a quick ultimate test - Table 100% with 2x 50% cols... with IMG in each with 100% width... failed completely.. and output miniature images

Comment: I use TCPDF. It is good, but lacks CSS capability.

Comment: It's 2020 and I'm having a really hard time creating something with dompdf. And I'm not talking about having to use CSS2. Basic things like table rendering, floats doesn't work, its all buggy and you have to wonder why do the borders go too much to the left, or why does the first element has no border. Trying to work around inline blocks and div tables to make it work.

Answer (score 565, accepted):

**Important:**
Please note that this answer was written in 2009 and it might not be the most cost-effective solution today in 2019. Online alternatives are better today at this than they were back then.

Here are some online services that you can use:

- [PDFShift](https://pdfshift.io)
- [Restpack](https://restpack.io/html2pdf)
- [PDF Layer](https://pdflayer.com)
- [DocRaptor](https://docraptor.com)
- [HTMLPDFAPI](https://htmlpdfapi.com)
- [HTML to PDF Rocket](https://www.html2pdfrocket.com)

---

Have a look at [PrinceXML](http://princexml.com).

It's definitely the best HTML/CSS to PDF converter out there, although it's not free (But hey, your programming might not be free either, so if it saves you 10 hours of work, you're home free (since you also need to take into account that the alternative solutions will require you to setup a dedicated server with the right software))

Oh yeah, did I mention that this is the first (and probably only) HTML2PDF solution that does full [ACID2](http://princexml.com/samples/acid2/acid2.pdf)?

[PrinceXML Samples](http://princexml.com/samples/)

Answer (score 674):

Have a look at [`wkhtmltopdf`](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) . It is open source, based on webkit and free.

We wrote a small tutorial [here](http://beebole.com/blog/general/convert-html-to-pdf-with-full-css-support-an-opensource-alternative-based-on-webkit/).

**EDIT( 2017 ):**

If it was to build something today, I wouldn't go that route anymore.
But would use http://pdfkit.org/ instead.
Probably stripping it of all its nodejs dependencies, to run in the browser.

Answer (score 153):

After some investigation and general hair-pulling the solution seems to be [HTML2PDF](http://html2pdf.fr/).  [DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) did a terrible job with tables, borders and even moderately complex layout and [htmldoc](http://www.easysw.com/htmldoc/) seems reasonably robust but is almost completely CSS-ignorant and I don't want to go back to doing HTML layout without CSS just for that program.

HTML2PDF looked the most promising but I kept having this weird error about null reference arguments to node_type.  I finally found the solution to this.  Basically, PHP 5.1.x worked fine with regex replaces (preg_replace_*) on strings of any size.  PHP 5.2.1 introduced a php.ini config directive called **pcre.backtrack_limit**.  What this config parameter does is limits the string length for which matching is done.  Why this was introduced I don't know.  The default value was chosen as 100,000.  Why such a low value?  Again, no idea.

A [bug was raised against PHP 5.2.1 for this](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40846), which is closed.

What's horrifying about this is that when the limit is exceeded, the replace just **silently fails**.  At least if an error had been raised and logged you'd have some indication of what happened, why and what to change to fix it.  But no.

So I have a 70k HTML file to turn into PDF.  It requires the following php.ini settings:

- pcre.backtrack_limit = 2000000; # probably more than I need but that's OK
- memory_limit = 1024M; # yes, **one gigabyte**; and
- max_execution_time = 600; # yes, **10 minutes**.

Now the astute reader may have noticed that my HTML file is smaller than 100k.  The only reason I can guess as to why I hit this problem is that html2pdf does a conversion into xhtml as part of the process.  Perhaps that took me over (although nearly 50% bloat seems odd).  Whatever the case, the above worked.

Now, html2pdf is a resource hog. My 70k file takes approximately 5 minutes and at least 500-600M of RAM to create a 35 page PDF file.  Not quick enough (by far) for a real-time download unfortunately and the memory usage puts the memory usage ratio in the order of 1000-to-1 (600M of RAM for a 70k file), which is utterly ridiculous.

Unfortunately, that's the best I've come up with.

Answer (score 129):

Why don’t you try [mPDF version 2.0](http://www.mpdf1.com/)? I used it for creating PDF a document. It works fine.

Meanwhile mPDF is at version 5.7 and it is actively maintained, in contrast to HTML2PS/HTML2PDF

But keep in mind, that the documentation can really be hard to handle. For example, take a look at this page: https://mpdf.github.io/.

Very basic tasks around html to pdf, can be done with this library, but more complex tasks will take some time reading and "understanding" the documentation.

Comment: **NOTE** `mPDF` is currently up to version 8.2 and is one of only a very, very few PDF generator scripts that works on PHP 8.1+ .

Answer (score 74):

1. use [MPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/) !
   ==

a) extract in `yourfolder`

b) create **file.php** in `yourfolder` and insert such code:

```
<?php
include('../mpdf.php');
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p style="color:red;">Hallo World<br/>Fisrt sentencee</p>');
$mpdf->Output();   exit;
 ?>
```

c) open **file.php** from your browser

## 2) Use [pdfToHtml](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdftohtml/) !

1. extract **pdftohtml.exe** to your root folder:
2. inside that folder, in **anyfile.php** file, put this code (assuming, there is a source example.pdf too):
3. enter **FinalFolder**, and there will be the converted files (as many pages, as the source PDF had..)

Answer (score 58):

Checkout [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/). It has some HTML to PDF functionality that might be enough for what you need. It's also free!

Comment: **NOTE:** FYI This process does not work with PHP 8 and the newer version is still in process and not ready to use.

Comment: @Martin TCPDF doesn't?

Answer (score 33):

Just to bump the thread, I've tried DOMPDF and it worked perfectly. I've used `DIV` and other block level elements to position everything, I kept it strictly CSS 2.1 and it played very nicely.

Answer (score 32):

I suggest **[DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com)** (which uses `PrinceXML` as the "engine")

Answer (score 32):

**Good news! [Snappy](https://github.com/knplabs/snappy)!!**

Snappy is a **very easy** open source PHP5 library, allowing thumbnail, snapshot or PDF generation from a url or a html page. And... it uses the **excellent** webkit-based **[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)**

Enjoy! ^_^

Answer (score 30):

It's already been mentioned, but I'd just like to confirm that mpdf is the easiest, most powerful and most free HTML to pdf converter out there. The sky's really the limit. You can even generate pdf of dynamic, user-generated data.

For instance, a client wanted a CMS system so he could update the tracklist of the music he played at his club. That was no problem, but he also wanted users to be able to download a .pdf of the playlist, and so this downloadable pdf had to be updated by the cms too. Thanks to mpdf, with some simple loops and interspersed variables I could do just that. Something that I thought would take me weeks literally took me minutes.

Great [article](http://www.smaizys.com/php/mpdf-html-to-pdf-introduction/) that helped me get started.

Answer (score 27):

Well if you want to find a perfect XHTML+CSS to PDF converter library, forget it. It's far from possible. Because it's just like finding a perfect browser (XHTML+CSS rendering engine). Do we have one? IE or FF?

I have had some success with DOMPDF. The thing is that you have to modify your HTML+CSS code to go with the way the library is meant to work. Other than that, I have pretty good results.

See below:

[Original HTML](http://www.nutquote.com/quote/William_Shakespeare/1/simple)

[Converting HTML to PDF](http://www.converthub.com/htmltopdf.php?html=http://www.nutquote.com/quote/William_Shakespeare/1/simple)

Answer (score 26):

The **HTML2PDF and HTML2PS** that was originally mentioned in opening post was talking about a 2009 package with this [link](http://tufat.com/html2ps-and-html2pdf/)

But there is a better [HTML2PDF](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default)

It is based on TCPDF though it is partly in French.

You can have table headers or footers that repeat on the pages and have page numbers and total pages. See [its examples](http://html2pdf.fr/en/example). I have been using it for over three years and recommend it.

Answer (score 23):

I am using [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) to produce PDF files using PHP. It's working well for me so far to produce simple outputs.

Answer (score 22):

There's a tutorial on Zend's devzone on generating pdf from php ([part 1](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1254-PDF-Generation-Using-Only-PHP---Part-1), [part 2](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1255-PDF-Generation-Using-Only-PHP---Part-2)) without any external libraries. I never implemented this sort of solution, but since it's all php, you might find it more flexible to implement and debug.

Answer (score 17):

Darryl Hein's mention above of [TCPDF](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf)  is likely a great idea.  Nicola Asuni's code is pretty handy and powerful.  The only killer is if you ever plan on merging PDF files with your generated PDF it doesn't have those features.  You would have to create the PDF and then merge it using something like PDFTK by Sid Steward (www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).

Answer (score 16):

Try grabbing the latest nightly **dompdf** build - I was using an older version that was a terrible resource hog and took forever to render my pdf. After grabbing a nightly from [here](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/).

It only took a few seconds to generate the PDF - AND it was just as nicely rendered as with **PrinceXML** / **Docraptor**. Seems like they've seriously optimized the **dompdf** code since I last used it!

Answer (score 13):

In terms of cost, using a web-service (API) may in many cases be the more sensible approach. Plus, by outsourcing this process you unburden your own infrastructure/backend and - provided you are using a reputable service - ensure compatibility with adjusting web standards, uptime, short processing times and quick content delivery.

I've done some research on most of the web services currently on the market, please find below the APIs that I feel are worth mentioning on this thread, in an order based on price/value ratio. All of them are offering pre-composed PHP classes and packages.

1. [pdflayer.com](https://pdflayer.com) - Cost: $ - Quality: ☆☆☆☆
2. [docraptor.com](http://docraptor.com) - Cost: $$$ - Quality: ☆☆☆☆☆
3. [pdfcrowd.com](http://pdfcrowd.com) - Cost: $$ - Quality: ☆☆☆

**Quality:**

Having the high-quality engine `PrinceXML` as a backbone, [DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com) clearly offers the best PDF quality,  returning highly polished and well converted PDF documents. However, the [pdflayer API](https://pdflayer.com) service gets pretty close here. [Pdfcrowd](http://pdfcrowd.com) does not necessarily score with quality, but with processing speed.

**Cost:**

**pdflayer.com** - As indicated above, the most cost-effective option here is pdflayer.com, offering an entirely free subscription plan for 100 monthly PDFs and premium subscriptions ranging between $9.99-$119.99. *The price for 10,000 monthly PDF documents is $39.99.*

**docraptor.com** - Offering a 7-Day Free Trial period. Premium subscription plans range from $15-$2250. *The price for 10,000 monthly PDF documents is ~ $300.00.*

**pdfcrowd.com** - Offering 100 PDFs *once* for free. Premium subscription plans range from $9-$89. *The price for 10,000 monthly PDF documents is ~ $49.00.*

I've used all three of them and this text is supposed to help anyone decide without having to pay for all of them. This text has not been written to endorse any one product and I have no affiliation with any of the products.

Answer (score 12):

If you have access to the command line it's possible to use **PhantomJS** to create the `PDF` from an `URL` (remote or local).

It works really well, and is a free solution.

Take a look at this [example](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) script made for this exact problem.

Answer (score 11):

This question is pretty old already, but haven't seen anyone mentioning [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) so I will :)

**CutyCapt**

> [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) is a small cross-platform command-line utility to
>   capture WebKit's rendering of a web page into a variety of vector and
>   bitmap formats, including SVG, PDF, PS, PNG, JPEG, TIFF, GIF, and BMP

Answer (score 11):

I recommend TCPDF or DOMPDF, in that order.

Answer (score 9):

I dont think a php class will be the best for render an xHtml page with css.

What happen when a new css rule come out? (soon css 3.0...)

The best way to render an html page is, obvisiuly, a browser.
Firefox 3.0 can natively 'print' in pdf format, torisugary developed an extension (command line print) to use it. [Here you'll find it.](http://torisugari.googlepages.com/commandlineprint2)

Anyway, there are still many problmes runninr firefox *just* as a pdf converter...

At the moment, i think that wkhtmltopdf is the best (that is the one used by the safari browser), fast, quick, awesome.
Yes, opensource as well... 
[Give it a look](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

Comment: PHP is useful if you want to output some type of official documentation such as a receipt for a user and you can use CSS to make it look nice.

Answer (score 9):

I developed a public API to build PDF files from web pages. It has a nice PHP client class that makes it super easy to use. It uses wkhtmltopdf to render the PDF in the cloud.

No need for anything special in the HTML. No need for absolute URLS in images/css/js links. Works on localhost (dev machine) too.

Currently the service has endpoints in 4 Azure regions: US East, US West, EU North, Southeast Asia.

It's fast since it uses a proprietary protocol to send the web page contents to the API for conversion to PDF.

It's reliable because all endpoints are load balanced.

Free account available for testing or low usage. Details on the web site:

https://rotativahq.com

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps you might try and use Tidy before handing the file to the converter. If one of the renderer chokes on some HTML problem (like unclosed tag), it might help it.

Comment: Yes a valid point but I've thought of this already.  There are no unmatched nor nonstandard tags in my HTML.

Answer (score 7):

Fine rendering doesn't mean anything. Does it validate?

All browsers do the most they can to just show something on the screen, no matter how bad the input. And of course they do not do the same thing. If you want the same rendering as FireFox, you could use its rendering engine. There are pdf generators for it. It is an awful lot of work, though.

Answer (score 7):

Although there are many solutions offered already, I recommend the following two:

1. [HTM2PDF](http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk) - offers an API to convert HTML to PDF and also has a PHP SDK, which makes it very easy to implement in PHP; It offers a choice of server locations in Europe, Asia and the USA
2. [PDFmyURL](http://pdfmyurl.com) - offers an API that does URL and HTML to PDF as well, with roughly the same functionality as HTM2PDF, but works on a load balanced landscape and has been around a little longer

The thing that's different about these two APIs from all the previously mentioned solutions, is that - besides converting HTML to PDF with CSS and JavaScript - it also offers PDF rights management, watermarking and encryption. Therefore it's an all-in-one solution for those who want to hit the ground running.

Disclaimer: I work for Kaiomi, a company that operates both of these websites.

Comment: I wouldn't want to rely on a service when [it's up for sale](https://flippa.com/2965195-pr-6-internet-site-with-50-000-uniques-mo-making-2-000-mo). Given the fact that it was unsold in that auction, I can only assume it will be sold in the near future?

Comment: actually my company acquired it some time after the auction....

Comment: In that case, I suppose there is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 5):

Does the HTML to PDF conversion really *need* to occur server-side using PHP?

I just came across [jsPDF](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf), a client-side solution using HTML5/JavaScript. The MIT-licensed [code is on GitHub](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), too.

Comment: for me, the library is very limited

Answer (score 5):

TCPDF works fine, no dependencies, is free and constantly bugfixed. It has reasonable speed if supplied HTML/CSS contents is well formated. I normally generate from 50 - 300 kB of HTML input (including CSS) and get PDF output within 1-3 secs with 10 - 15 PDF pages.

I strongly recommend using **tidy** library as HTML pretty formatter before sending anything to TCPDF.

Comment: **NOTE** TCPDF is no longer maintained and does not work at all on PHP8+

Comment: @Martin Did you check with github repo ? - https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF It is maintained, last commit about 6 weeks ago (ver. 6.2.1), though no new features. Runs on my PHP 8.2 as well. Repo with new features is at https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-pdf

Comment: Yes. There are a stack of fatal errors on various parts of the library using discontinued PHP 7 functions. You can also verify this that many parts of the github base are many years old so pre-date PHP 8.

Comment: @Martin What discontinued PHP 7 functions? Where is stack of fatal errors? You mean on version TCPDF 6.2.1 ? Perhaps check your TCPDF version in changelog..

Answer (score 4):

I've tried a lot of different libraries for PHP. All the listed I've tried. 
In my opinion [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) library is the best compromise performance/usability.
It's very simply to install and use, also good performance in small medium application.
If you need high performance and very big PDF document, use [Zend_PDF](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.html) module, but get ready to coding hard!

Comment: Zend PDF can't convert from HTML

Answer (score 3):

## Web API

If there is people who always search for this kind of stuff, there is a **free** website which allow you to convert html code & pages to pdf. There is also a (very small) api which allow you to get pdf file from url.

[**Check it here**](http://simplehtmltopdf.com)

Answer (score 2):

not **PHP**, but a [**Java** library](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/), which does the thing:

> Flying Saucer takes XML or XHTML and applies CSS 2.1-compliant
>   stylesheets to it, in order to render to PDF

It is usable from **PHP** via `system()` or a similar call. Although it requires **XML** well-formedness of the `input`.